# Perform function in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this function that returns a bool(true) or bool(false) if the `movement` exists.

```
function movement_performed_today($class_id, $client_id){
$class_id = (int)$class_id;
$client_id = (int)$client_id;



$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`movement`) FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `class_id` = '$class_id' AND `client_id` = '$client_id' AND `date` = CURDATE()");

$movement_performed = mysql_fetch_row($query);
return ($movement_performed[0] > 0);

}
```

I have this while loop where I want to call this function and if it returns false perform the function `completed_movement`. I have tried many different ways but I just can't seem to get it to work. Any info will be much appreciated.

```
if (empty($_POST)=== false){
$i = 0;
while (isset($_POST["first_name"][$i])) {
    $movement_data = array(   
    'user_id'       => $session_user_id,   
    'class_id'      => $class_id,   
    'class_name'    => $class_name,
    'client_id'     => $_POST['client_id'][$i],    
    'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'][$i],   
    'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'][$i],   
    'nickname'      => $_POST['nickname'][$i],   
    'order'         => $_POST['order'][$i],   
    'movement'      => $_POST['movement'][$i],   
    'rep_set_sec'   => $_POST['rep_set_sec'][$i],   
    'rest'          => $_POST['rest'][$i],   
    'date'          => $today   
    );  

 //assign variable to the function
    $isPerformed = movement_performed_today($class_id, $_POST['client_id'][i]);

    //if return false perform this function
    if(! $isPerformed){ completed_movement($movement_data);}

   $i++; 
   } 

} // if empty
```

What Im trying to do here is each time it loops through check to see if the function movement_performed_today is true or false. If returns false then insert this _POST data in to db. Not sure if Im doing this correctly because even though the function returns true it still calls the completed_movement function and post the info to db.

I believe the issue may lie here. Earlier this would return true or false but now just returns false even though the `movement` is present. This code:

```
$movement_performed = mysql_fetch_row($query);
//return ($movement_performed[0] > 0);
var_dump($movement_performed);
```

Returns this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" }
```

If the `movement` is present shouldn't "0" be "1" or higher depending the number of times it matched up with the query.

Here is the working query:

```
function movement_performed_today($class_id, $client_id, $movement){
$class_id = (int)$class_id;
$client_id = (int)$client_id;



$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`movement`) FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `class_id` = '$class_id' AND `client_id` = '$client_id' AND `movement` = '$movement' AND `date` = CURDATE()");

$movement_performed = mysql_fetch_row($query);  
return ($movement_performed[0] > 0);

}
```

Here is the working while loop.

```
if (empty($_POST)=== false){
$i = 0;
while (isset($_POST["first_name"][$i])) {
    $movement_data = array(   
    'user_id'       => $session_user_id,   
    'class_id'      => $class_id,   
    'class_name'    => $class_name,
    'client_id'     => $_POST['client_id'][$i],    
    'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'][$i],   
    'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'][$i],   
    'nickname'      => $_POST['nickname'][$i],   
    'order'         => $_POST['order'][$i],   
    'movement'      => $_POST['movement'][$i],   
    'rep_set_sec'   => $_POST['rep_set_sec'][$i],   
    'rest'          => $_POST['rest'][$i],   
    'date'          => $today   
    );  

 //check not already performed today
    $isPerformed = movement_performed_today($class_id, $_POST['client_id'][$i], $_POST['movement'][$i]);

    //if not performed then do insert
    if (! $isPerformed){ completed_movement($movement_data);}

   $i++; 
   } 

} // if empty
```

Thanks guys for all your help!

Comment: You don't seem to send the right variable to `movement_performed_today`. Shouldn't `$_POST['client_id']` be `$_POST['client_id'][$i]`?

Comment: this did help but it will still call the function `completed_movement` if if the `$isPerformed` returns true.

Comment: Have you checked if your query is ok? Did you try to `echo` it? Did you try to dump `$movement_performed` to see if the result is as expected? We pointed out a few mistakes, but we can't debug this script for you. Why

Comment: @MathieuImbert yes I can do a var_dump and return bool(false) or bool(true) depending if the `movement` exists.

Comment: @MathieuImbert yes the check performs properly but when I call it in the while loop and if it returns false (no movement found) to perform function `movement_completed` but no matter what I try it performs `movement_completed` even though `$isPerformed` returned true.

Comment: If `$isPerformed` is true, `if(! $isPerformed){` won't be executed. It is probably executed in another iteration, but this mean your logic os flawed. Try dumping `$isPerformed` at each iteration and add a `echo completed_movement;` inside your if to see what's happening. Try to follow step by step to see at what value of `$i` data is wrongly inserted. The try to figure out why. As I said before, I don't have access to your code, so I'm giving up.

Comment: @MathieuImbert I added new code above show what Im getting from a var_dump.

Answer (score 3):

I may be misreading this but it looks like you are setting $return to true or false, not actually returning the value. I believe you want to change:

```
$return = $movement_performed[0] > 0;
```

to

```
if($movement_performed[0] > 0) return true;
else return false;
```

Comment: this help part of the problem but it still will perform the function `complete_movement` if the `$isPerfomed` returns `true`

Comment: Try it with an if statement instead of returning the result of the condition directly.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

It sounds like you have trouble with your SQL query as well. Try:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`movement`) FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `class_id` = $class_id AND `client_id` = $client_id AND `date` = CURDATE()");
```

Since columns class_id and client_id appear to be integers, remove the single quotes around their values.

Edit: Corrected syntax, converted SQL result to integer first.

`return ((int)$movement_performed[0] > 0 ? true : false);`

If you use this return line, the function `completed_movement()` will return only booleans.

In this case, you want to be strict when doing comparison logic for calling the function.

You'll want to do this:

```
//if return false perform this function
if ($isPerformed === false) {
    completed_movement($movement_data);
}
```

Comment: @Colbyd Check my edits. Where are the variables $session_user_id, $class_id, $class_name, $today coming from? If they're from the POST, you'll need to extract the values from the POST into the variables.

Comment: `$class_id` is actually assigned earlier in the page and its a _GET variable.

Comment: @Colbyd Hmm, in this case, try converting the returned value from the DB into an integer first to compare with 0.

Comment: @Colbyd No worries, check out the line of code I've edited in my answer. I added (int) before the SQL result value in order to convert it to an integer.

Comment: I added code above to show it's for some reason returning false even though the `movement` is there.

Comment: @Colbyd Can you try adding 'echo $movement_performed[0];' right above the return line to see what the value is?

Comment: `echo $movement_performed[0]` returns `00` so it is returning false for both rows of data. Im not sure what to do different. Should I be using something other than `mysql_fetch_row`?

Comment: @Colbyd I'm looking at your revised question now. Instead of `return ($movement_performed[0] > 0);` use the line of code I've included in my current answer.

Comment: that does not work because the query is returning false when it shouldn't be. If I run the query in PhpMyAdmin and replace `$class_id` and `$client_id` with actual `id's` i get this`COUNT(movement) 7`. So when I did the `echo $movement_performed` it should of returned 77 because both clients have the same `movement` in the table on todays date

Comment: @Colbyd OK, then that sounds like the MySQL query is the issue. It's good you're trying to use strict syntax in the query, but a lot of the backticks you have aren't necessary. Also remove the single quotes around the values for the class_id and client_id columns.

Comment: @Stegrex....First off I want to thank you for all your help. It finally works. I feel really stupid right about now. This was the culprit `[i]` should of been this `[$i]` I have posted the working code above. Thanks again for your time.!